# Is it possible to freeze chocolate covered ants?

Tags: chocolate

I have a recipe for chocolate covered ants and wanted to make it a few weeks ahead of time before a party - if I freeze them will they still be good in about two weeks?

Comment: You can freeze them, and they will be exactly as good as they were when you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't even need to freeze them. Chocolate has a very long shelf life in your pantry, from 1-2 years depending on fat/milk content.

You can freeze it, but it may affect the texture or appearance.

Comment: What, no link to safety standards or shelf life for ants?!?

Comment: I had ants in my shelves for months and months. no problem there.

Comment: @shabbychef Were they alive?