# How long can you keep chocolate in the freezer?

Tags: food-safety, freezing, chocolate

We get lots of gifts of chocolate and due to health reasons, we can't finish all the chocolate. So we store it in the freezer. How long can or should you  store chocolate in the freezer before it's not safe to eat anymore?

Comment: Welcome Aurora,look at [this question here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/is-it-possible-to-freeze-chocolate-covered-ants), it might give you a clue.

Answer (score 5):

My wife is obsessed with [Milka](http://www.milka.com/), and last time we were in Germany, she threw out all my clothes in order to fill an entire suitcase with it. When we got it home, it got piled in the freezer (not the freezer-in-the-garage-which-is-seldom-opened, but the regular one where we keep ice cream and frosty beer mugs). Took us more than 4 years to finish it. The last bit was effectively identical to the first. No noticeable change in the product.

Given that quality chocolate has no water (which is the primary freezer-spoilage agent), I'd say it would keep effectively indefinitely. If you're talking about candy bars which contain other ingredients, it may vary.

Generally though, things don't go "bad" in the freezer. They can get brutally freezer burned and disgusting, but there is no safety issue, as long as the food remains frozen. I once made a pie out of a quart of blackberries I found buried in the ice in an old-style freezer chest. Estimated age was on the order of twenty years, but they'd been preserved by the encroaching frost. Pie was delicious.

Comment: 20 year old pie thats gotta be a record ;)

Comment: @rfusca: Admittedly, if I had known they were that old, I'd probably have avoided them, but all I saw was a couple of big bags of berries...We'd been defrosting the thing for about a day, and they'd emerged from the glacier without me noticing, and I didn't want to put partly thawed berries in the other freezer, so, you know, pie. Then grandma staggers in and goes, "*sniff* *sniff* Smells like blackberry pie. Haven't had a blackberry pie since your granddad died. He picked all the berries." So I said, "So who picked these?" She looks at the label on the bag, "Your granddad." Me: "Oh."

Comment: I've left chocolate out and it's been fine after months and months.  In the freezer, it lasts even longer.  Happiness is putting on a winter coat for the first time in the fall and finding a chocolate Easter egg in the pocket.

Comment: @thursday: Yea, I keep my baking chocolate in the regular fridge, and never for a moment consider how long its been there.

Answer (score 2):

I froze some milk chocolate buds in 1999, took them out today. No sign of freezer burn, looked and smelled good, so I tasted one. Tastes like original. No side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Even on the shelf chocolate has a very long life, at least months if not years. When it does go bad, it becomes chalky, but is still not dangerous. 
 In the freezer it should last more or less indefinitely.

Comment: I just realized how old the question is. If you did put your chocolate in the freezer, it's probably still good.