# Is it OK to freeze chocolate?

Tags: baking

is it ok to freeze chocolate and for how long? I received 50 lbs of chocolate chips from my sister.  I want to freeze some but not sure how long they will last.

Comment: Why would it not be ok? What are your concerns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can you keep chocolate in the freezer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17691/how-long-can-you-keep-chocolate-in-the-freezer)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, perfectly fine to freeze it. It will last approximately forever, frozen.

Related: [How long can you keep chocolate in the freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17691/how-long-can-you-keep-chocolate-in-the-freezer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes chocolate can be frozen if required, it can extend the shelf life by 50% if not more, but not forever.  It is suggested to slow the cooling/freezing process.

Depending on how you want to use it, depends on whether you need to carefully thaw it out before using.

Many professional chocolatiers have information on these topics online.